# How do i get from $\frac{y'}{y}=\alpha\frac{A'(x)}{A(x)}+\beta\frac{B'(x)}{B(x)}+\gamma\frac{C'(x)}{C(x)}$ to [desired answer]

Tags: derivatives

Again, I'm trying to follow an example in my textbook.

Basically, we're trying to find the derivative with respect to $x$ of

$$y(x)=[A(x)]^\alpha[B(x)]^\beta[C(x)]^\gamma$$

According to the book, the first step is to take the natural logarithm, so:

$$ln(y)=\alpha*ln(A(x))+\beta*ln(B(x))+\gamma(ln(C(x))$$

I'm onboard so far, but in the next step, the book states that the derivative with respect to x is:

$$\frac{y'}{y}=\alpha\frac{A'(x)}{A(x)}+\beta\frac{B'(x)}{B(x)}+\gamma\frac{C'(x)}{C(x)}$$

The explanation goes on for a while longer, but this step leaves med dumbfounded. How and why is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

That step is using the [chain rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

For instance, if you have $y=\log\left(f(x)\right)$, then differentiating with respect to $x$, we have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\log\left(f(x)\right)\right)}{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(f(x)\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{f(x)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(f(x)\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

In general if you have $F(x)=f(g(x))$, then differentiating with respect to $x$ you will get:

$$F'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$

Comment: Sure, if we took the derivative of  $ln(A(x))$ we would get the product of the outer and inner functions, and $\frac{1}{A(x)}*A'(x)=\frac{A'(x)}{A(x)}$

That's not my question, but rather, how can the derivative of a product be written like that?

We are "not" taking the derivative of $\alpha∗ln(A(x))+\beta∗ln(B(x))+\gamma (ln(C(x))$, we're taking the derivative of $e^{\alpha∗ln(A(x))}*e^{\beta ln(B(x))}*e^{\gamma*(ln(C(x))}$ and as such we should be using the product rule.

Comment: Also, I can't see why the derivative of $e^{ln(y)}$ should be any different than the derivative of $y$, that is to say $y'$.

Comment: @Magnus It's not different. Like you said, we know $e^{\ln(y)}=y$ so the derivative for both is simply $y'$

Comment: ....Sure, but then why is it written as $\frac{y'}{y}$???

Comment: @Magnus it's because it's not the derivative of $e^{\log(y)}$ instead it's the derivative of just $\log(y)$. Derivative of $e^{\log(y)}$ is simply $y'$ because essentially $e^{\log(y)}=y$ but the derivative of $\log(y)$ is $\frac{y'}{y}$ if you follow the chain rule.

Comment: Right, that doesn't anwer why such a step would be "necessary" but I guess that wasn'r part of my questoin, marking this as best answer.

Comment: @Magnus Taking $\log$ of both sides was necessary to separate $A(x),B(x),C(x)$ into a sum and also to make the exponents of $A(x),B(x),C(x)$as a product. If you don't take $\log$ the differentiation would get ugly and then you would have to use **product** rule as well in addition to the chain rule.